# Angular Routing and Navigating

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, navigateurl

My `app.component.html` is very light

```
<div class="landing-page">
   <div class="main">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <div class="footer"> 
         <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <a routerLink="/"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" srcset="assets/images/logo@2x.png 2x,assets/images/logo@3x.png 3x" /></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a the following routes defined in `AppRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: 'book/:id', component: BookComponent },
  { path: '**', component: LandingPageComponent }
];
```

in my `LandingPageComponent` I'm navigating to the `book` like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { 
}

OpenBookComponent(id){        
    this.router.navigate(["/book", id], {skipLocationChange: true});
}
```

Up to this point everything works perfect.

The **problem** start when returning to the main page by navigating to `["/"]`

Both clicking back `<` in the browser or programmatically trying to navigate from `BookComponent` to the base link, reveal the full path in the address bar (i.e.: `http://localhost:4200/book/123`) and results in **displaying only the footer**

my code navigating back in `BookComponent` is:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
    
}
ngOnInit() {        
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');       
}
closeBook(){      
   this.router.navigate(["/"], {skipLocationChange: true});
}
```

How can I clear all parameters from the address when going back, so it remains just `/` or `http://localhost:4200` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete the parameters. You must just add a new route like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'book/:id', component: BookComponent },
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: LandingPageComponent }
];
```

Now if you want to navigate to `"['/']"`, you can write it like this, as an example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" class="nav-link active">Back</a>
```

And now it would display the component, where you have written behind `''` in the angular routes array, in this case the `LandingPageComponent`.